# How to create yaboot partition using a ppc Mac

Tags: osx, boot-loader, live-usb

My computer g4 1.5 ghz PowerBook ppc

I need to use this computer to make a yaboot partition on a USB stick.

Here is documentation for making a yaboot partition with a Linux machine:
http://penguinppc.org/bootloaders/yaboot/doc/yaboot-howto.shtml/index.en.shtml

but how do I do this with Mac OS 10.5?

Answer (score 1):

[Yellow Dog Linux](http://www.yellowdoglinux.com/products/ydl/) had great documentation on using yaboot back in the day. It all appears to be still available [here](http://www.yellowdoglinux.com/support/solutions/ydl_general/yaboot_kernel.shtml).